# Androis studio - APP aborting shortly after starting

Tags: android

I just finished a project in android studio and I have a problem here. When generating the application and installing on the smartphone (android nougat 7.1.1 oneplus3) it simply aborts. In the emulator it gives the message that the application stops and aborts. I need the help of you more experienced. I'm a beginner. Here's the LOGCAT lines below when you try to open the application:

```
    08-16 13:51:44.610 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-16 13:51:44.610 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
08-16 13:51:45.249 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto-1/lib/x86_64
08-16 13:51:45.281 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-16 13:51:45.576 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-16 13:51:45.647 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/Chrome/lib/x86_64
08-16 13:51:45.648 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/app/Chrome/lib/x86_64:/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/x86_64:/system/lib64:/vendor/lib64 for namespace 0x7fcbeb8400f0
08-16 13:51:45.650 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 55.0.2883.91 (code 288309162)
08-16 13:51:45.670 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 9774-9776)
08-16 13:51:45.670 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
08-16 13:51:45.678 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
08-16 13:51:45.678 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(163)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
08-16 13:51:45.683 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
                                                                                       
                                                                                       [ 08-16 13:51:45.692 13313:13313 D/         ]
                                                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fcbd18d6000, tid 13313
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
                                                                                       [ 08-16 13:51:45.694 13313:13313 W/         ]
                                                                                       Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
08-16 13:51:45.696 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fcbde5c12a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-16 13:51:45.697 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fcbde5c12a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fcbd18f1c20)
08-16 13:51:45.798 13313-13359/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
08-16 13:51:45.807 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is enabled.
08-16 13:51:45.885 13313-13368/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-16 13:51:45.885 13313-13368/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
                                                                                    
                                                                                    [ 08-16 13:51:45.885 13313:13368 D/         ]
                                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fcbcdea13c0, tid 13368
                                                                                    
                                                                                    
                                                                                    [ 08-16 13:51:45.888 13313:13368 W/         ]
                                                                                    Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
08-16 13:51:45.892 13313-13368/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fcbcdf532c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-16 13:51:45.904 13313-13368/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fcbcdf532c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fcbcdfb3920)
08-16 13:51:45.979 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
                                                                            
                                                                            [ 08-16 13:51:45.980 13313:13374 D/         ]
                                                                            HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fcbcd52f2e0, tid 13374
                                                                            
                                                                            
                                                                            [ 08-16 13:51:45.982 13313:13374 W/         ]
                                                                            Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
08-16 13:51:45.995 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fcbcdf55ca0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-16 13:51:45.998 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fcbcdf55ca0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fcbcd54d900)
08-16 13:51:46.018 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
08-16 13:51:46.050 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-16 13:51:46.054 13313-13368/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fcbcdf532c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fcbcdfb3920)
08-16 13:51:46.067 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
08-16 13:51:46.088 13313-13324/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.371ms
08-16 13:51:46.167 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7fcbcdf569c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-16 13:51:46.169 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7fcbcdf569c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7fcbcd54d900)
08-16 13:51:46.175 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
08-16 13:51:46.176 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
08-16 13:51:46.176 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
08-16 13:51:46.176 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
08-16 13:51:46.180 13313-13374/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/libEGL: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
08-16 13:51:46.707 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 13313
08-16 13:51:46.709 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-16 13:51:46.716 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-16 13:51:46.752 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
08-16 13:51:46.753 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
                                                                                    
                                                                                    
                                                                                    --------- beginning of crash
08-16 13:51:46.753 13313-13313/agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto, PID: 13313
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at agdesenvolvimentoweb.projetopiloto.MainActivity$MyWebViewClient.onPageFinished(MainActivity.java:161)
                                                                                        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:545)
                                                                                        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:201)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting dismiss() on your progress bar somewhere in your code with out having initialised it.

do

```
 if(progress!= null)
     progress.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put only your application's log.

Second, you are trying to dismiss a progress dialog when its not initialized.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
```

I'd start my inspections with `MainActivity.java:161`